# In Regular Expression what is the different between \^n and \b

Tags: javascript, regex

In Regular Expression

- `/^n/`
- `/\b/`

I always confuse them

So could you explain to me the difference between them and when to use each of them?

Comment: `I always confuse them` You described their behavior already, what exactly do you confuse about them?

Comment: Your descriptions for these 2 regex patterns already explain well what they match.  What is your question?

Comment: Is question about *the difference between the beginning of a string and the beginning of a word* ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` means beginning of whole text line.
`\b` means beginning of word, but line could hold many words, obviously.

```js
// Search for n only at the beginning of LINE
console.log(1, "no yes".match(/^n/));
console.log(2, "yes no".match(/^n/));

// Search for n at the beginning of ALL words in line (with flag g)
// or only for first one without g flag
console.log(3, "yes no yes no".match(/\bn/g));
console.log(4, "yes no yes no".match(/\bn/));
```